# How Can I Get Connected Media Devices in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, webcam

I'm going to prepare an application(charp) that ask users to which web cam thay want to use and get streams from selected webcam. To do that, I need to search and find connected webcams to computer this is my first step. second step is getting streams from that webcam. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code - based on `ManagementObjectSearcher` `class`

```
static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
      List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

      ManagementObjectCollection collection;
      using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
        collection = searcher.Get();      

      foreach (var device in collection)
      {
        devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
        ));
      }

      collection.Dispose();
      return devices;
    }
```

Comment: Selecting * has a great impact on performance. Use `Select DeviceID, PNPDeviceID, Description From Win32_USBHub` instead.